# Как получить капчу с сайта. c#

Tags: c#, base64, captcha

Доброго времени суток, нужно получить капчу с сайта, капча имеет такой урл :

```
data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJYAAAAyCAAAAACb533GAAAD/0lEQVR4nO1ZS5bjMAgkeTlK3f9EdZhZCAkQJTtJd+9Gi7ZbHyj+yHnQ8kD993omLcVr339Y0Rt99lVnjzQFAVOoLiiwnDhs9NmXXOz7OqoPJFikmqJP6B6fKOiE6n2IY2dVm0Lw+A6VYvb1dqGy58/wjMd7qDBfuE2RwLb3WQ4IGreTPxmccu2C3WiriaHJXtN4f/Pa8bSzawBoYlwS0+MKzmntrC2AClSlQ9zwPfHWTrL4vaqyIp8Y/RFxgt1X/ZWs+gYxTs2jTmNsAw3jGEoqK6NrC5MSAJo1O8Iw9xgHixqKMBhIA8wBGIvCEA9Qq/rRJDWs+EAS1SIXlqWWDoeGh7KcThweb66wSUdY4+RbtIP9zcI8bhuxai2Ik1ZgAHewdTw3qhPOkCJ4z7V4Ic0Mki7V665T+FP2HkJbw5lorCpOJN1wQlUBNDmQBO1MJpdt9JoIM8IB1UhsjFiknevud7Ye+jxhHH4mxqFUh8jSp23OiU5wpAeb4cHe/9nMFefxLBIogHKiuVvwZm1WdPkS+aLDuoHeg+JqE4qVu7IuqRRYk+CBXZ3XYXDi+WXT8Uxkou1JFgGNhTjNqPNCYJFZfQuWe1hrc1hiAtXXEzNgZjelj1J3ErWFaZweQwWUyFtAY5uFX7QBL48bsNA9XNFL96MMeiKVIvukSqczurVf0O04ybRsmLmiejyXeqlST0gwYVXvGaSIFevVibOGlNBTsJbbjNNTxrFjpzbTaWm0Vm9TRSgC5Dg4loHDekEj/ffVKeTAWZ1bG3OO0ud7Xsmgk0AgDMxqodlF0zyrDwBrFybHyrS1eoH7ey/nIaE3kYXyujzs2irNW05flXiwk/nBYDR4bSwpbDktc+BkqgdY2iq66fa2fF8ZsSJQDz9P8ZKQFcGPvfwknyCkl8gPsx9s0MLC4QLjaKSy5YFgvcJ2WIfeL+EePgHk2MjLpcqArJf51ck5Lipmot/CNbDhMam7stDWnjPgyCqBaC1Xk7QrW3Sn61YT5CtVZ4xc5NoGouikn19klAJUTcyn0ULYqbEXQ1/lSgulY1w4/A97DVCwKo9hcXIveRwcs7ckX+Wqz/Qs0erLsvm0Ru8CCqx1PmKIsH6rZjQBDIeKw/SmZWamdiuf+xEo21CROOrDaFvAXZqUqZDukCibxozsQbqU17BCXemhCgdJXVl8dZw7V3LGLBV901+aMYJsfI5YBys5m5VlmTz1IJMFdsfK9Qy5cOy2LF+a1+3womM4TtVvz6e8p35rWIUqaUtWurdQXZ3ql+m2HbsZ8ihGPGf226tKZ3t3iPs3+iy58q2O6mNQ7wCjneU9/1ygLgDfjrvq38av/Irx++Nnv2L82fgP65PxDyDyCbf/kaIHAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

Если вставить это в поле ввода браузера, то покажет саму капчу. Но мне нужно получить это средствами c#, xnet(к примеру).

Если я правильно понял, то никакого урл нет, тут закодирован исх код png изображения в base64, не подскажите, как правильно ее обработать ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Преобразования base64 из вашего примера в изображение:

```
string captcha = "data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJYAAAAyCAAAAACb533GAAAD/0lEQVR4nO1ZS5bjMAgkeTlK3f9EdZhZCAkQJTtJd+9Gi7ZbHyj+yHnQ8kD993omLcVr339Y0Rt99lVnjzQFAVOoLiiwnDhs9NmXXOz7OqoPJFikmqJP6B6fKOiE6n2IY2dVm0Lw+A6VYvb1dqGy58/wjMd7qDBfuE2RwLb3WQ4IGreTPxmccu2C3WiriaHJXtN4f/Pa8bSzawBoYlwS0+MKzmntrC2AClSlQ9zwPfHWTrL4vaqyIp8Y/RFxgt1X/ZWs+gYxTs2jTmNsAw3jGEoqK6NrC5MSAJo1O8Iw9xgHixqKMBhIA8wBGIvCEA9Qq/rRJDWs+EAS1SIXlqWWDoeGh7KcThweb66wSUdY4+RbtIP9zcI8bhuxai2Ik1ZgAHewdTw3qhPOkCJ4z7V4Ic0Mki7V665T+FP2HkJbw5lorCpOJN1wQlUBNDmQBO1MJpdt9JoIM8IB1UhsjFiknevud7Ye+jxhHH4mxqFUh8jSp23OiU5wpAeb4cHe/9nMFefxLBIogHKiuVvwZm1WdPkS+aLDuoHeg+JqE4qVu7IuqRRYk+CBXZ3XYXDi+WXT8Uxkou1JFgGNhTjNqPNCYJFZfQuWe1hrc1hiAtXXEzNgZjelj1J3ErWFaZweQwWUyFtAY5uFX7QBL48bsNA9XNFL96MMeiKVIvukSqczurVf0O04ybRsmLmiejyXeqlST0gwYVXvGaSIFevVibOGlNBTsJbbjNNTxrFjpzbTaWm0Vm9TRSgC5Dg4loHDekEj/ffVKeTAWZ1bG3OO0ud7Xsmgk0AgDMxqodlF0zyrDwBrFybHyrS1eoH7ey/nIaE3kYXyujzs2irNW05flXiwk/nBYDR4bSwpbDktc+BkqgdY2iq66fa2fF8ZsSJQDz9P8ZKQFcGPvfwknyCkl8gPsx9s0MLC4QLjaKSy5YFgvcJ2WIfeL+EePgHk2MjLpcqArJf51ck5Lipmot/CNbDhMam7stDWnjPgyCqBaC1Xk7QrW3Sn61YT5CtVZ4xc5NoGouikn19klAJUTcyn0ULYqbEXQ1/lSgulY1w4/A97DVCwKo9hcXIveRwcs7ckX+Wqz/Qs0erLsvm0Ru8CCqx1PmKIsH6rZjQBDIeKw/SmZWamdiuf+xEo21CROOrDaFvAXZqUqZDukCibxozsQbqU17BCXemhCgdJXVl8dZw7V3LGLBV901+aMYJsfI5YBys5m5VlmTz1IJMFdsfK9Qy5cOy2LF+a1+3womM4TtVvz6e8p35rWIUqaUtWurdQXZ3ql+m2HbsZ8ihGPGf226tKZ3t3iPs3+iy58q2O6mNQ7wCjneU9/1ygLgDfjrvq38av/Irx++Nnv2L82fgP65PxDyDyCbf/kaIHAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";

string base64 = captcha.Split(',')[1].Trim();

var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
using (var imageFile = new FileStream("test.jpeg", FileMode.Create))
{
    imageFile.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    imageFile.Flush();
}
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827081/c-sharp-base64-string-to-jpeg-image

Comment: А зачем `Flush`, если у вас всё равно `using`?

Answer (score 3):

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
using(var stream = new MemoryStream(data, 0, data.Length))
{
  Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
  //TODO: do something with image
}
```